# python 3.6 aiohttp is slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, aiohttp

I have a python web application to return some data from a DB. But when I have 100 concurrent users, it gets much slower. First, I thought it's the DB issue. But everything works fine on the DB. So I removed all the DB related code. It's just an aiohttp service by itself.

```
import asyncio
import asyncpg
from aiohttp import web
import os
import logging
import sys
import time

async def handle(request):
    return web.Response(text="hi")

async def init_app():
    """Initialize the application server."""
    app = web.Application()

    # Configure service routes
    app.router.add_route('GET', '/', handle)
    return app

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(levelname)7s: %(message)s',
    stream=sys.stderr,
)
LOG = logging.getLogger('')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
app = loop.run_until_complete(init_app())
web.run_app(app)
```

Now, if I run one user, the response time is 2ms. But if I put 100 users, the response time 295 ms. Is this the nature of the aiohttp?

Comment: Please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think your server spends the most time on printing incoming requests to stderr.

Logging to console is quite expensive, file or network is relatively cheap.

Comment: So I removed all the logging pieces.  Running one user, the average response time is still 2ms. Then run 100 concurrent users, the response time is 103ms. It's improved a lot. But still there is about 100ms overhead under the load. Anything else can be done?